# Add Voltage Bias/Offset to 2nd-Order Sallen-Key Highpass

Tags: operational-amplifier, bias, active-filter, high-pass-filter, sallen-key

I need to add a highpass filter between a signal source and an ADC to get rid of high-amplitude low-frequency signals that would cause clipping.

I built a second-order Sallen-Key filter and the circuit is working as expected. However the filter requires a symmetric power supply and I need to run it on a single supply.

This is what I have:

[image]

- The input `U_IN` is a 0V ... 3.3V signal (the attached sensor has low output impedance).
- The filter is currently configured to have gain 1.1 (R2=1k, R1=10k) but a unity gain with a voltage follower would work aswell (the exact gain is not critical).
- The Op-Amp currently is supplied with +3.3V and -3.3V.
- The cutoff frequency is at 500Hz.

In addition I already have a reference voltage source (voltage divider and buffer) that provides half of the maximum signal voltage (1.65V):

[image]

How can I change the filter to output 0V ... 3.3V while supplying the Op-Amp with +3.3V and GND?

Comment: You don't say what Op-Amp you are using, but very few will drive their outputs rail-to-rail. But have a look at the OPS340 https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa340-ep.pdf or the similar OPA 353 https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa353.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be kicking yourself to see how easy this is.

[image]

But perhaps you should review where is the 0V signal = "ground" and how can you use an INA with shielded twisted pair to eliminate the low frequency (grid) voltage noise from high E or H fields.

Comment: Also split R1 with two 20K resistor just as R3 did. Use 0 - 5Vdc supply.  Add a series capacitor at the output. and use 1% resistor for the split to minimize any additional DC offset.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine (I went for unity gain with voltage follower). How do you know the value of R3 and the new resistor? The values need to be equal to center the signal at half the supply voltage. But how do you calculate their exact values (why did you double the 3.3k?).

Comment: @KevinWhite: Having the output centered on 1.6V is exactly what I wanted. I need to read the value with an ADC that has the range 0 ... 3.3V.

Comment: @Johannes , because these Resistors are effectively in parallel you need exactly twice the values.  In series it adds, but in //  it is the ratio of product and sum https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130267/calculating-r-with-2-resistors-parallel

Comment: @Johannes - sorry, my confusion.